# utf8_general_ci in SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, collation

```
CREATE TABLE 'product_desc' (
  `index` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `item_no` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `product_no` int(3) NOT NULL default '0',
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`index`)
) ENGINE=product set CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This is an example I found online to create table in MySQL.

I want to create a similar table in SQL Server 2008 R2, I want to know -

1. What is similar collation to "utf8_general_ci" in SQL Server 2008 R2 (fyi I will be saving arabic latter, column data type will be nvarchar(max), I have used "arabic_ci_as" but some of the latter is not recognized)
2. Is it possible in SQL server 2008 R2 that I set collation at individual column level?
3. how do you set "CHARACTER SET utf8" in SQL server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

For number 2. Check MSQL [manual.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ve/library/ms190920.aspx)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
  (PrimaryKey   int PRIMARY KEY,
   CharCol      varchar(10) COLLATE French_CI_AS NOT NULL
  );
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN CharCol
            varchar(10)COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL;
```